# sequelize posting NULL in database(MySql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: { autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        firstname: { type: Sequelize.STRING, notEmpty: true },
        lastname: { type: Sequelize.STRING, notEmpty: true },
        //username: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
        //about: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
        mobileno: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        email: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { isEmail: true } },
        password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        last_login: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
        //status: { type: Sequelize.ENUM('active', 'inactive'), defaultValue: 'active' }

    });

    return User;
}
```

Everything else is posting fine but `mobileno` is being posted as `null` in database.

I tried setting mobile no as `allowNull = false` but that gives me an error.

I also tried changing string to text but that didn't help either...

[image]

this is the eroor after adding allowNull=false..

Comment: For the code example you posted, it is expected that `mobileno` = `null`. If you set it to: `allowNull: false`, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems is in your data not in your sequelize model

Based on your question I think you send the empty value for `mobileno` field

About `AllowNull` parameter: when you will set the false it's means sequelize will return error if you will not pass parameter (which happens in your case)

By default `AllowNull` value is `true`

My suggestion is to check you data before insert query also when you will run create command using sequelize check console it's will show you insert into sql format

Comment: found my prob...i wasnt parsing it correctly...tats why it was sending null value to database...

Answer (score 1):

After checking the [documentation](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/models-definition.md#validators-and-allownull) your code is working normally.

```
 // setting allowNull to false will add NOT NULL to the column, which means an error will be
 // thrown from the DB when the query is executed if the column is null. If you want to check that a value
 // is not null before querying the DB, look at the validations section below.
 title: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
```

Before saving to the db, you need to validate your info to make sure that `mobileno` is not `null`. Once you have a value for `mobileno` you can save it to the `db`.